# removing html tag's attribute with regexp and backreference

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove the "style" attribute from a html attribute
I've achived this goal with this regular expression:

```
"<div id='mioId'  style='color:black;background-color:red' attr='stuff' class='myClass' />".replace(/style=('|")[^('|")]*\1/, '')
```

what I would like to do, is using the backreference also to match the content.
something like this:

```
"<div id='mioId'  style='color:black;background-color:red' attr='stuff' class='myClass' />".replace(/style=('|")[^\1]*\1/, '')
```

in my head this last solution should work, but regular expressions seem not agree with me...

note: I'm note interested in other approach, I just want to understood what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backreferences cannot be used inside [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Instead of using a **negated** character class, you have to use a [Negative Lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookarounds).

```
.replace(/style=(['"])(?:(?!\1).)*\1/, '')
```